# Xpath is correct but Scrapy doesn't work

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, spyder

I'm trying to download two fields from a webpage, I identify the XPath expressions for each one and then run the spider, but nothing is downloaded.

The webpage:
http://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04MZH

The field I want to itemize is `ISIN`.

The spider runs without errors, but the output is empty.

Here is the line code:

```
item['ISIN'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="overviewQuickstatsDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove `tbody` from XPath:

```
'//*[@id="overviewQuickstatsDiv"]/table//tr[5]/td[3]/text()'
```

Note that this tag is added by your browser while page rendering and it's absent in page source

P.S. I suggest you to use IMHO even better XPath:

```
'//td[.="ISIN"]/following-sibling::td[contains(@class, "text")]/text()'
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this won't work? --> item['score'] = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="mainContentDiv"]/table/tr/td/ec-sustainability/div/div[1]/div[1]/h3/text()').extract()

Comment: The element has a warning about "use $0 in the console to refer to this element"...

Comment: I see no child nodes in `ec-sustainability` node. What output you want exactly?

Comment: There is a text ("Sin Rating") that I would like to get in that same line. I have tried several things but nothing works...

Comment: Just a string `"Sin Rating"` or `"- | - "` or something else?

Comment: Just the string "Sin Rating", it just means "Without rating"

Comment: Try `//div[@id="mainContentDiv"]//div[*[name()="svg"]]/following-sibling::h3/text()`

Comment: XPath is correct, but the value is dynamic, so you'll not get the data with Scrapy

Comment: Offtop: You should let moderators know about series of downvotes. Maybe they can investigate the issue and do something about it...

Answer (score 0):

I think response.selector was not given. Try this.

```
response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="overviewQuickstatsDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/text()').extract()
```